# how to use pandas to return a list of etf components' ticker?

Tags: python, pandas, finance, datareader, pandas-datareader

I am using pandas DataReader and selenium, and I want to write a function that enters an ETF ticker and returns a list of components' ticker.
I found the code below to achieve that but there are some problems with this code.

import pandas as pd
#from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver

def get_etf_holdings(etf_symbol):

```
#etf_symbol: str

#return: pd.DataFrame
url = 'https://www.barchart.com/stocks/quotes/{}/constituents?page=all'.format(
    etf_symbol)

# Loads the ETF constituents page and reads the holdings table
browser = WebDriver() # webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get(url)
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html')
table = get_table(soup)

# Reads the holdings table line by line and appends each asset to a
# dictionary along with the holdings percentage
asset_dict = {}
for row in table.select('tr')[1:-1]:
    try:
        cells = row.select('td')
        # print(row)
        symbol = cells[0].get_text().strip()
        # print(symbol)
        name = cells[1].text.strip()
        celltext = cells[2].get_text().strip()
        percent = float(celltext.rstrip('%'))
        shares = int(cells[3].text.strip().replace(',', ''))
        if symbol != "" and percent != 0.0:
            asset_dict[symbol] = {
                'name': name,
                'percent': percent,
                'shares': shares,
            }
    except BaseException as ex:
        print(ex)
browser.quit()
return pd.DataFrame(asset_dict)
```

but an error occurs when i run the code. i wonder how to fix it? the error is shown below.
"selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see [https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home"](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home%22)

Answer (score 1):

You have to download chromedriver so that selenium can use chrome to access barcharts.com.

Download link: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=84.0.4147.30/

It's a little bit of a process but after downloading the zip, take the extracted .exe file and put it in folder that's on your PATH variable. For most people this can be /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin, or maybe even a /Scripts folder. You can check that chromedriver has been properly added to PATH by opening up a command prompt and typing `chomedriver` and if you don't get a `chromedriver is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` then you're good. Your code should work from there!

Read more about installation and usage of selenium at https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html

Comment: the problem is solved. But do you know why the code is using BeautifulSoup but this package is not imported beforehand? and I didn't see the def get_table(), which caused an error in my compiler.

Comment: good point, in the original alpaca website they don't have the full code. but I did find the full code here https://github.com/alpacahq/blogmaterials/blob/master/001-etf-replicator/etf-replicate.ipynb

Comment: @ChenJin if this solves your question, considering marking the answer.

Comment: I tried to use another method which is almost there. But there is still some minor issues caused from DataReader. Can you take a look at it?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63202190/fail-to-read-symbol-while-using-pandas-datareader

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to do some web scraping (which requires some packages), since etf components can change over time. You can do this by using some code I found on https://alpaca.markets/learn/python-etf-trading-api/ with some alterations to fit your needs, but it may be a good idea to look through the article.

This pulls data from [barcharts.com](https://www.barchart.com/) and parses through it to get the names.

```
import pandas as pd
# brew install phantomjs
# or
# brew tap homebrew/cask
# brew cask install chromedriver

# from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver

def get_etf_holdings(etf_symbol):
    # etf_symbol: str



    url = 'https://www.barchart.com/stocks/quotes/{}/constituents?page=all'.format(
            etf_symbol)
    # Loads the ETF constituents page and reads the holdings table
    browser = WebDriver() # webdriver.PhantomJS()
    browser.get(url)
    html = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html')
    table = get_table(soup)

    # Reads the holdings table line by line and appends each asset to a
    # dictionary along with the holdings percentage
    assets = []
    for row in table.select('tr')[1:-1]:
        try:
            cells = row.select('td')
            # print(row)
            symbol = cells[0].get_text().strip()
            # print(symbol)
            name = cells[1].text.strip()
            assets.append(name)
        except BaseException as ex:
            print(ex)
    browser.quit()
    return assets
```